The kinetic energy of rigid body
I need to determine the kinetic energy of ball rolling with out slipping on a cylinder, and when I searched for it I found that the kinetic energy is:
$$ T = \tfrac12mv^2 + \tfrac12I\omega^2 $$
But the center of mass of the ball does not moving in a line but on a circle,
so I ask why the kinetic energy is not calculated with the equation:
$$ T = \tfrac12 I\omega^2 + \tfrac12 I'\omega'^2 $$
Where:

$I$ : the moment of inertia around the center of mass(CM) of ball

$\omega$ : the angular velocity of the ball around the CM

$I'$ : the moment of inertia around the center of cylynder

$\omega'$ : the angular velocity around the center of cylinder



How does the center of mass move in a circle?

When the ball rolling on the cylinder the center of the ball moves on the circle of rad = rad of cylinder + rad of ball

Oops sorry. Missed it was rolling on a cylinder

$+{1 \over 2} mv^2$ with $v$ the speed along the cylinder.

The kinetic energy due to the ball's rotation about its own centre is given by the $\frac 1 2 I \omega^2$ term. So to calculate the kinetic energy due to the ball's revolving around the centre of the cylinder, we can treat the ball as a point mass located at its centre of mass. If this centre of mass is a distance $r$ from the centre of the cylinder then we have $I' = mr^2$ and $\omega' = \frac v r$. So the second term $\frac 1 2 I' \omega'^2$ is actually equal to
$\displaystyle \frac 1 2 \left( mr^2 \right) \left( \frac {v^2}{r^2} \right) = \frac 1 2 m v^2$
In other words the two expressions for the kinetic energy of the ball are actually equal.

But why we can dealing with ball as a point when we calculate the moment of inertiea around the cylnder center

So if we assume that the ball does not rolling any more and it just slipping on so the cylender the kinetic energy can be calculated depend on the definition of kinetic energy of rigid boudy by calculate the kinetic of samll parts of the boude and add them to gather in another words to by ingeral the velocity with respect to dm so if we apply this we will conclude that we can't dealing with ball as a point

@FadiGorgos (1) Because the kinetic energy due to the ball's rotation about its own centre is already included in the $\frac 1 2 I \omega^2$ term; (2) if the ball is slipping and not rolling then $\omega=0$ and you are just left with the translational kinetic energy $\frac 1 2 mv^2$.

Thanks for you, so all the points of ball has the same velcity when the ball slipping on the cylinder?

Beware that rolling something around a round object, you might get an off-by-one difference, and that would turn up as a slightly different angular velocity.

Yes...the angular velocity calculated by make the common point betwen ball and cylinder has the same velocity when it belongs to the tow rigid bodys
